# In Ready Player One, what happens if a student dies?

Tags: ready-player-one

In *Ready Player One*, the Oasis has permadeath, with a person whose avatar died having to create a new avatar from scratch, with no XP, items, or anything else their old avatar might have had.

What happens if a student in enrolled the Oasis's public schools on Ludus dies (whilst on another world, of course, since combat is banned on Ludus)? Will the student have to completely re-enroll in school, with no record of their credit completions? Or does the school have an "exception" to the permadeath rule?

Comment: _(currently reading the book)_ As far as I know Ludus is not a combat world, so zero deaths. No info (yet) about suspensions and such though.

Comment: There was no way for a student on the planet to die.

Comment: @NKCampbell The students leave Ludus all the time though! They can die on  **other worlds**, hence my question

Comment: I think you are confusing an Oasis avatar with an Oasis account

Comment: @NKCampbell - Technically, avatars could die in the Tomb on Ludos. Just not a PvP zone.

Answer (score 14):

> When I'd first enrolled in the OASIS public school system, I was required to give them my real name, avatar name, mailing address, and Social Security number. That information was stored in my student profile [...]
>
> <sub>*Ready Player One*, chapter "0002"</sub>

The OASIS public school system is tied to the person in the real world, through their real name and SSN.

Presumably, when an avatar dies, the student has to create a new avatar and register it with their account.

> If my avatar was killed, I would lose my sword, shield, and leather armor, and the three levels I'd managed to gain over the past few years. I'd have to create a new first-level avatar, which would spawn at my last log-in location, in front of my school locker.
>
> <sub>*Ready Player One*, chapter "0007"</sub>

Comment: Actually, I just finished finding the other "avatar death" quote I remembered and now I think there is a canon conflict? From chapter 37 - ...good thing too since my OASIS account and everything in it was just erased...

Comment: Though that is a quote from a character and I suppose it is possible she was "wrong" in her assumption... Also the situation of someone who has stuff in their OASIS account for work that would lose it all if they died while on a quest during their free time (only one account per person) seems like a big design flaw...

Comment: It doesn't actually make much sense for account metadata to be erased alongside player death. RPG equipment maybe, but if Avatar death caused all the money in your account to be deleted, it seems unlikely that the OASIS credit would be considered a stable currency.